# Порядок уничтожения временных объектов

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer

Недавно столкнулся с некоторой странностью при уничтожении временных объектов. Собственно, вопрос следующий: почему объект под номером 2 удаляется раньше объекта под номером 1? Разве не должны выполняться деструкторы аргументов при выходе из области видимости, то есть при возврате из функции? Почему вначале удаляется временный объект из функции `main`, а затем аргумент `foo`? Почему не наоборот?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::clog;

struct A {
    static size_t counter;
    size_t me = counter++;
    A() { clog << "constructor A: " << me << "\n"; }
    A(const A& o) { clog << "copy A: " << me << "\n"; }
    A(A&& o) { clog << "move A: " << me << "\n"; }
    ~A() { clog << "destructor A: " << me << "\n"; }
};
size_t A::counter = 0;

A foo(A obj) {
    clog << "into foo\n";
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    clog << "before foo\n";
    foo(a);
    clog << "between foo\n";
    A other = foo(a);
    clog << "after foo\n";
}
```

Вывод:

```
constructor A: 0
before foo
copy A: 1
into foo
move A: 2
destructor A: 2
destructor A: 1
between foo
copy A: 3
into foo
move A: 4
destructor A: 3
after foo
destructor A: 4
destructor A: 0
```

Компилятор GCC 5.1.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Деструкторы вызываются в порядке обратном относительно вызывов конструкторов пл принципу стека LIFO (Last Input First Output).
Сначало был создан объект с номером 1 посредством вызова конструктора копирования, так как исходный объект это `lvalue` . В стек также был занесен его деструктор. 
Затем внутри функции был вызван конструктор перемешения с номером 2 благодаря RVO (return value optimization). Этот конструктор вызван после конструктора параметра, а, следовательно, его деструктор помещен в стек перед деструктором объекта с номером 1.

Таким образом последним помещенным в стек, объект с номером 2 удаляется первым.

Согласно стандарту C++ (12.2 Temporary objects)

> 5....The destruction of a temporary whose lifetime is not extended by being bound to a reference is **sequenced before the destruction of
>   every temporary which is constructed earlier in the same
>   full-expression**.

Переводя на русский язык, эта цитата из стандарта говорит о следующем:
"Уничтожение временного объекта, чье время жизни не продлевается за счет привязки к ссылке, происходит перед уничтожением каждого временного объекта, который был создан ранее в том же самом полном выражении"

Что касается второго предложения

```
A other = foo(a);
```

то временный объект строится непосредственно в объекте `other`, а потому и удаляется, когда сам этот объект удаляется.

Если вы посмотрите на сообщения, которые сосответствуют этому предложению

```
move A: 4
destructor A: 3
after foo
destructor A: 4
```

то вы увидите, что благодаря RVO (return value optimization) локальный объект функции (ее параметр), который является `lvalue`, сразу же перемещается в объект `other`. На это указывает сообзения

```
after foo
destructor A: 4
```

То есть этот временный объект был построен в `other` и, соответственно удален после сообщения

```
after foo
```

когда функция main завершила свою работу.

Comment: @ixSci я думаю, дело в https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule

Comment: @ixSci Я удалил это предложению:)

Comment: Не могли бы вы перевести фразу из цитаты? А то что-то я не могу понять её.

Comment: @mymedia Смотрите мое обновленное сообщение.

Comment: Ага, тогда ясно. Но только тут не говорится про то, что все временные объекты уничтожаются в *конце* полного выражения. Получается, MVSC тоже действует правильно.

Comment: @mymedia Тут важно другое: в каком порядке были созданы  объекты. Ведь вас интересует почему объект 2 удаляется перед удалением объекта 1.

Comment: Эм… в таком случае получается, что аргумент — это тоже временный объект. Потому что он подчиняется правилам, по которым уничтожаются временные объекты. Даже не смотря на то, что его не надо вычислять.

Comment: @mymedia но аргументы конструируются до локальных переменных, поэтому и уничтожаться должны позже (по идее)

Comment: @mymedia Здесь скорее всего имеет место, что для возвращаемого значения и благодаря RVO имеется условно представляемое подвыражение return_value = std::move( obj ); Так как return_value далее не используется, то это выражение сразу же удаляется, то есть удаляется временный объект, созданный в нем.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, да, но в данном случае аргумент уничтожается ещё чуть позже, после удаления других временных объектов в выражении `foo(a)`

Comment: @mymedia нет, 1 - аргумент, 2 - временная переменная.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, да. И GCC удаляет аргумент после временного объекта, который вернулся из функции.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko На мой взгляд это происходит из-за RVO. То есть внутри сгенерированного объектного кода функции стоит предложение, как, например, other = std::move( obj );. В случае, когда объекта назначения нет, то выглядит как A temporary = std::move( obj );. Этот сгенерированный код стоит на месте предложения return. Поэтому этот временный объект удается перед удалением параметра.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я в своем ответе ровно то же написал :)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, RVO совершенно точно не играет здесь роли, т.к. вне зависимости от степени оптимизации вывод на всех компиляторах стабилен. В отсутствии оптимизации никакого RVO генерироваться не может.

Comment: @ixSci Как это не играет роли, когда вывод программы однозначно показывает, что компилятор использует конструктор перемещения для lvalue и строит объект сразу в объекте назначения? Если бы не было RVO, то сначала бы локальный объект скопировался бы во временный объект, а уж затем этот временный объект переместился бы в объект назначения.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, там чистое перемещение, никакого копирования там вообще нет. `return object;` при условии, что `object` имеет конструктор перемещения всегда вызовет его. Никакого копирования. Ну или сработает NRVO. Тогда вообще никакого конструктора вызвано не будет.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, судя по всему такая конструкция(возврат аргумента функции) вообще убивает (N)RVO. Вот [пример](http://ideone.com/FegwBv) с NRVO, с тем же кодом, только немного изменённым - посмотрите его вывод, тогда всё станет ясно.

Comment: @ixSci Как это убивает RVO, когда используется конструктор перемещения для параметра функции в объект назначения? Без RVO сначала из параметра с помощью конструктора копирования должен быть создан временный объект, и лишь затем этот временный объект перемещен в объект назначения.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, да нет же. В выражении `return object;` `object` уже является `xvalue`, а значит подлежит перемещению, если таковое возможно. Только в противном случае он будет скопирован.

Comment: @ixSci  Разве в общем случае не должен компилятор сначала создать временный объект, соответствующий выражению в предложении return, и только затем копировать его в переменную назначения?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, если не требуется конвертации - нет не должен. Объект либо копируется во внешний объект, либо перемещается, либо срабатывает (N)RVO. Но никаких дополнительных копий не создаётся. Это было бы глупо, если бы на каждый *локальный* объект, который и так подлежит уничтожению, создавать ещё и копию. Копию нужно было бы создавать, если бы объект передавался в функции по ссылке, а потом возвращался по значению. В этом случае была бы создана копия, но опять же, это копия будет только одна и она сразу пойдёт "наружу".

Comment: @ixSci В стандарте в разделе 12?.8 #31 есть такой пример Thing f() {
Thing t;
return t;
}
Thing t2 = f(); относительно которого говорится, что здесь в общем случае должны быть вызваны два конструктора копирования, и один из них - это копирование локального объекта во временный объект для значения return.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, да, очень интересная находка. Никогда не подозревал, что по стандарту в таком случае должно быть 2 копирования. А не подозревал я по одной простой причине - так никто не делает. К примеру, заставить MSVC сделать вторую копию просто невозможно, а gcc/clang только с флагом `-fno-elide-constructors`. Если использовать ухищрения, по "поломке" NRVO, то остаётся только одно копирование: [пример](http://rextester.com/live/CLJ87073). Второе всё равно не появляется, таким образом о нём вообще можно забыть, т.к. ни при каких условиях этого второго копирования быть не может.

Comment: По крайней мере в современных, распространённых компиляторах. Я вообще не понимаю, зачем в стандарте упоминается вторая копия. Она же совершенно не нужна. Но о теоретической возможности было интересно узнать, спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Почему у GCC такой порядок я честно говоря не знаю, у MSVC он другой - такой какой напрашивается. Но с моей точки зрения GCC имеет право на подобное поведение, т.к. стандарт говорит следующее:

> **[5.2.2/4]**: The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns. The initialization and destruction of
>   each parameter occurs within the context of the **calling function**.

Таким образом, параметр будет уничтожен уже после выполненного `return` в вызывающей функции. Но и возвращаемое значение будет уничтожено сразу по выходу из функции, т.к. выражение на этом заканчивается и все временные объекты из оного подлежат уничтожению.

В принципе, возвращаемое значение "моложе" аргумента, а значит должно быть уничтожено до него. С другой стороны, деструктор возвращенного значения можно рассматривать как функцию, которая должна быть вызвана позже удаления аргумента. Таким образом можно считать, что стандарт несколько размыт в данном случае, а можно считать, что поведение GCC более соответствует стандарту.

---

Предлагаю добавить в примеру всего пару строк, и всё станет ещё интереснее:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::clog;

struct A {
    static size_t counter;
    size_t me = counter++;
    int a;
    void foo()
    {
        clog << "foo me\n";
    }
    A() { clog << "constructor A: " << me << "\n"; }
    A(const A& o) { clog << "copy A: " << me << "\n"; }
    A(A&& o) { clog << "move A: " << me << "\n"; }
    ~A() { clog << "destructor A: " << me << "\n"; }
};
size_t A::counter = 0;

A foo(A obj) {
    clog << "into foo\n";
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    clog << "before foo\n";
    foo(a).foo();
    clog << "between foo\n";
    A other = foo(a);
    clog << "after foo\n";
}
```

Вывод MSVC2013(Release):

```
constructor A: 0
before foo
copy A: 1
into foo
move A: 2
destructor A: 1
foo me
destructor A: 2
between foo
copy A: 3
into foo
move A: 4
destructor A: 3
after foo
destructor A: 4
destructor A: 0
```

GCC/Clang:

```
constructor A: 0
before foo
copy A: 1
into foo
move A: 2
foo me
destructor A: 2
destructor A: 1
between foo
copy A: 3
into foo
move A: 4
destructor A: 3
after foo
destructor A: 4
destructor A: 0
```

На мой взгляд логике стало ещё меньше и лично мне, вывод MSVC более логичен.

---

Видимо разница вызвана тем, что для MSVC аргумент функции это объект локальный для функции, тогда как для GCC/Clang это объект принадлежащий *full expression*. А если совместить цитату из моего ответа, с цитатой из ответа Vlad from Moscow, тогда получается, что GCC/Clang всё делают правильно, а MSVC отходит от стандарта.

---

Создал баг-репорт на [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1444021), посмотрим, что ответят.

---

Баг закрыли с формулировкой "by design" и привели [ссылку](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1880), где указывается, что такое поведение допустимо. Таким образом мы имеем, что MSVC не содержит проблемы, но его поведение отличается от GCC/clang.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю, что за аргументы ответственнен вызывающий? А как тогда стоит понимать имена параметров внутри тела функции? Получается, что это как бы "ссылки" на объекты из чужой функции, несмотря на то, что параметры передаются по значению.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что по стандарту все временные объекты уничтожаются только в конце полного выражения? И их нельзя уничтожать сразу, как только они стали не нужными.

Comment: @mymedia, это никакие не ссылки, они лежат в стеке и доступ к ним идёт прямой, просто создаются и удаляются они вызывающей функцией.

Comment: Лучше подправить баг-репорт, чтобы был минимальный пример

Comment: @mymedia, да, Вы всё понимаете правильно. Если объект имеет деструктор, и он является временным объектом в полном выражении, то его деструктор должен быть вызван только в конце этого выражения.

Comment: @ixSci, я имел ввиду, что это некий аналог `const T&` в списке параметров, но с возможностью изменения объекта.

Comment: @mymedia, нет, никакой это ни аналог ссылки. Не надо думать об аругументах по другому, после полученного сегодня знания. Они всё так же копируются в функцию.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko, я удалил всё ненужно, остальное там в тему, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @ixSci, ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Я подозреваю, что компилятор переписал функцию так:

```
A foo(A obj) {
    clog << "into foo\n";
    A result = std::move(obj);
    return result;
}
```

Clang, во всяком случае, выдает с ней такой же вывод. Тогда если забыть об RVO, то все выглядит логично. Но с RVO все равно у меня в голове не клеется. Скорее всего компилятор очень искусно притворяется, что не делает RVO.

Comment: Так в чём логичность? result dtor вызывается до obj dtor. Никакой логичности я тут не вижу.

Comment: @ixSci По-моему логично, что деструктор локальной переменной вызывается до деструктора аргументов. В x64 всегда caller cleanup

Comment: Понял Вашу логику, но она здесь не применима(т.к. нет NRVO) вызовите без оптимизации и вывод не изменится, а значит "result" по логике, переживает фигурную скобку.

Comment: @ixSci конечно переживает - место под него всегда определяет caller в своем фрейме. Это стандарт, c NRVO или нет. Тут дело в том, когда caller вызывает его деструктор - до деструкторов параметров или после, и тут вступает в ход правило as-if: локальная переменная должна быть уничтожена до параметров

Comment: Нет, компилятор не переписал так функцию. К сожалению, я не знаю, как сюда скинуть ассебленрый листинг, но вообще говоря, в самой функции foo не вызывается никаких деструкторов. Все деструкторы вызываются из main. Так, например, в функции main в строчке `foo(a);` вызываются два деструктора.

Comment: @mymedia ну да - caller cleanup же + NRVO. Но тут работает принцип as-if: компилятор генерирует код так, чтобы в рамках модели C++ нельзя было сказать, применяется NRVO нет, отсюда порядок деструкторов. Но возможно я неправ